# On the realization of a quotient group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a finite polyhedron and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G=\pi_1 (P)$. It is known that there exists a covering space $(\tilde{P},p)$ so that $p_* \pi_1 (\tilde{P})=N$. It follows that for the finite polyhedron $\tilde{P}$ (which is related to $P$), we have  $\pi_1 (\tilde{P})\cong N$.

My question is that:

Is there any finite polyhedron $Q$ (connected to $P$) so that $\pi_1 (Q)\cong \frac{G}{N}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems implausible, consider the case where $P$ is a graph. The quotient group can be an arbitrary finitely generated group, and while that is the fundamental group of a two-complex, it seems unlikely that this complex would have any intimate connection with the graph you started with.

Comment: Note that $\tilde{P}$ is only finite when $N$ has finite index in $G$.

Comment: Let $\{r_i\}$ normally generate $N$.  Represent (the conjugacy class of) each $r_i$ by a loop in the 1-skeleton of $P$. We can now define $Q$ by gluing a disc to $P$ for each $r_i$, using the corresponding loop as the attaching map.  This defines a cell complex that contains $P$. Of course, it can be taken to be finite if and only if $N$ is finitely generated as a normal subgroup.  It's unclear to me whether it's "connected to $P$" in the way that you want.  (@IgorRivin thinks not, but I prefer to leave it up to the OP to decide.)

Comment: Note that if, as you seem to imply in your question, you are actually interested in the case that $N$ has finite index in $G$, then there is a canonical finite choice: take the mapping cylinder of the covering map $\tilde{P}\to P$, and then cone off the end isomorphic to $\tilde{P}$.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you for the comment. You are right. This may happen. I check that.

Comment: @HJRW Yes. That's true. I mean that $N$ has finite index in $G$.

Comment: @HJRW Could you explain a bit more for the statement '' take the mapping cylinder of the covering map $\tilde{P}\longrightarrow P$ and then cone off the end isomorphic to $P$''?

Comment: What I want in my question is that ''Is there a finite polyhedron like $Q$ so that $\pi_1 (Q)\cong \frac{\pi_1 (P)}{\pi_1 (\tilde{P})}$? If there exists such polyhedron, then is there a special relation between $Q$, $P$ and $\tilde{P}$?

Comment: @MMhr, I'd be happy to explain more, but please first clarify what you want. Are you interested in all quotient groups $G/N$, or just finitely presented ones, or just finite ones?   Also, what exactly do you mean by "polyhedron"?  A simplicial complex?  The confusion arises because you assert in your question that $\tilde{P}$ is finite; but this is in fact only true when $G/N$ is finite.

Comment: @HJRW Thank you very much. Of course, finitely presented quotient groups. By a polyhedron I mean the underlying space of a finite simplicial complex. Yes. You are right. I mean $[G:N]<\infty$.

Comment: In that case, I've posted an answer which I hope clarifies what can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a finite polyhedron $P$ and finite-index normal  subgroup $N$ of $G=\pi_1P$, there is a canonical finite polyhedron $Q$ with $\pi_1Q\cong G/N$ constructed as follows. Let $\tilde{P}\stackrel{p}{\to} P$ be the covering map corresponding to $N$, as in the question.

We now construct the polyhedron $Q$ as follows:

$Q= ((\tilde{P}\times [0,1]) \sqcup P) / \sim$

where $(\tilde{x},0)\sim (\tilde{y},0)$ and $(\tilde{x},1)\sim p(\tilde{x})$, for all $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}\in\tilde{P}$.

That is, $Q$ is constructed from the mapping cylinder of the covering map $p$ by crushing the canonical copy of $\tilde{P}$ to a point. Alternatively, as I said in comments, one can think of this as obtained by gluing the cone on $\tilde{P}$ to the mapping cylinder of $p$.

The Seifert-van Kampen theorem then tells us that $\pi_1Q\cong \pi_1P/p_*\pi_1\tilde{P}\cong G/N$, as required.

Clearly, this construction can be performed for any subgroup $N$ of $G$, but only gives a finite polyhedron in the case when $N$ has finite index.  By making a choice, one may construct a suitable (non-canonical) polyhedron whenever $G/N$ is finitely presentable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. This is exactly what I want and expect. That's perfect. Thank you for taking the trouble to help me. I do appreciate you.